# reversing a linked list in ruby using a stack

Tags: ruby, algorithm, linked-list

I am implementing a reversed linked list using a stack. 
Class `Stack` has methods `push` and `pop`, which turn a linked list into a stack from which the last element can be extracted in order to reverse the order.

I've encountered a similar situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524081/reverse-a-linkedlist-without-using-array-methods), and I'm trying to add a method to that base case. I'm trying to implement a `reverse_list` method that makes use of the `Stack` class's `push` and `pop` in order to change the pointer and reverse the linked list.

This is what I tried:

```
class LinkedListNode
  attr_accessor :value, :next_node

  def initialize(value, next_node=nil)
    @value = value
    @next_node = next_node
  end
end

def print_values(list_node)
  if list_node
    print "#{list_node.value} --> "
    print_values(list_node.next_node)
  else      
    print "nil\n"
    return
  end
end

class Stack
    attr_reader :data

    def initialize
        @data = nil 
    end

    def push(value)
      @data = LinkedListNode.new(value, @data) 
    end

    def pop
      return nil if @data.nil?
      returning_value = @data.value
      @data = @data.next_element
      returning_value
    end
end

def reverse_list(list)
    stack = Stack.new.push(list.value)
    list = list.next_node

    while list
      stack.push(list.value)
      list = list.next_node
    end

    stack.pop
end

node1 = LinkedListNode.new(37)
node2 = LinkedListNode.new(99, node1)
node3 = LinkedListNode.new(12, node2)

revlist = reverse_list(node3)
print_values(revlist)
# should return 37 --> 99 --> 12 --> nil
```

I get errors when calling the `Stack` class in the `reverse_list` method (`undefined method push for <Context::LinkedListNode:0x00000001c5e0a8>`).

I'm at a loss as to why I cannot use `Stack`, `push`, and `pop` inside `reverse_list`. Any tips as to how I could go about implementing `reverse_list` will be well received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following pushes the elements into the stack, and then reverses them:

```
def reverse_list(list) 
    stack = Stack.new

    while list
      stack.push(list.value)
      list = list.next_node
    end

  LinkedListNode.new(stack.pop, stack.data)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

stack = Stack.new.push(list.value)

In your example, variable `stack` is an instance of `LinkedListNode` as `push` method is returning instance of linked list. So no method error is throwing. You have to create instance of `Stack` first like `stack = Stack.new` which woulb be an empty stack and then do push and pop operation using this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your pop Method within your Stack class is calling for "next_element", but I think you should be referring to the "next_node" variable from the LinkedListNode class. I would re-write your "pop" method this way:

```
def pop
 if @data.nil?
   nil
 else
   returning_value = @data.value
   @data = @data.next_node
   returning_value
 end
end
```

I would also rewrite the method to reverse the linked list like this:

```
def reversed_linked_list(list)
   stack = Stack.new
  while list
   stack.push(list.value)
   list = list.next_node
  end
  LinkedListNode.new(stack.pop, stack.data)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Iterate through the list adding its contents to a stack until the end of the list. After that, the following algorithm can be applied.

```
root = stack.pop() # last element
current = root
while not stack.empty():       # move in reverse direction
    current.next = stack.pop() # next element in stack is the next node
    current = current.next     # continue to the next node
current.next = nil             # mark end of the list
```

Comment: I think you're writing Python here. It's a Ruby question.

Comment: Please don't do that. If the question asks for Ruby, do Ruby. If you don't know Ruby, that's fine, but this isn't helping.